# Assign std::vector address of another std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector, stdvector

I'm writing a program to balance chemical equations. The program works by taking the equation string, splitting it up into a std::vector with a size of two based upon the equal sign, then parses the left side `separatedEquation[0]` and the right side `separatedEquation[1]` into another set of std::vector's leftHalf and rightHalf respectively.

**Problem**

I have a function Equation::filterEquation that parses the `separatedEquation` for the element names. I want to use a temporary vector that points to the address of either leftHalf or rightHalf. I know this is probably confusing, but here's my code and what I'mt trying to do. I think I need to use pointers, but I've never had to use pointers before and am not efficient with them.

```
void Equation::filterEquation()
{
    for(int i=0; i<separatedEquation.size(); i++) //i = index of separated equation
    {
        int index=0;
        std::vector<std::string> equationHalf;
        if(i==0)
            equationHalf = leftHalf; //set equationHalf to the address of leftHalf
        if(i==1)
            equationHalf = rightHalf; //set equationHalf to the address of rightHalf
        for (std::string::iterator it = separatedEquation[i].begin(); it!=separatedEquation[i].end(); ++it, index++)
        {
            //Elements are set up so that He = Helium, while H = Hydrogen. This separates the elements based upon upper and lowercae
            bool UPPER_LETTER = isupper(separatedEquation[i][index]); //true if character is upperCase
            bool NEXT_LOWER_LETTER = islower(separatedEquation[i][index+1]); //true if next is lowerCase
            if (UPPER_LETTER)// if the character is an uppercase letter
            {
                if (NEXT_LOWER_LETTER)
                {
                    std::string temp = separatedEquation[i].substr(index, 2);//add THIS capital and next lowercase
                    equationHalf.push_back(temp); // add temp to vector
                }

                else if (UPPER_LETTER && !NEXT_LOWER_LETTER) //used to try and prevent number from getting in
                {
                    std::string temp = separatedEquation[i].substr(index, i);
                    equationHalf.push_back(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Two `if` statements that overwire `equationHalf` at the beginning of the code segment seems wrong.

Comment: @sircodesalot I know, but I can't think of another way to do it. I had the two if statements set up like this originally: 
`if(i==0) {leftHalf.doSomething()}` and 
`if(i==1) {rightHalf.doSomething()}.

I thought it might be possible to override the address of equationHalf instead.

Comment: Well, what you have written can't possibly be what you mean because either `equationHalf` will *always* be `rightHalf` (`if i == 0`), or it will be nothing (if `i !=0`).

Comment: @sircodesalot Yes. That's a typo.

Comment: With your update, is it intended that `i` being *neither* `0` nor `1` will result in `equationHalf` being an empty vector going into the remainder of this function?

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right. The program separates the chemical equation based upon the `=`. In theory, `i` should only ever equal `0` or `1`. `equationHalf` should never be empty. Assume that there was a check to see if there is only 1 `=`. If there is only 1 `=` then `i` can only equal `0` or `1`.

Comment: If that is the case, then both the selected answer and the alternative reference initialization in my comment to the same answer should work. You have options. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general sense you would replace:

```
std::vector<std::string> equationHalf;

...

equationHalf = leftHalf // same for rightHalf
```

with

```
std::vector<std::string>* equationHalf;

...

equationHalf = &leftHalf // same for rightHalf
```

And then replace any instance of `equationHalf.` with `equationHalf->`.

Though, in your case, I might consider seriously reconsidering your design, for instance breaking out the code that operations on `equationHalf` into a function and passing it a reference to the `vector` to operate on such as `void doStuff(std::vector<std::string> & equationHalf)`, then simply calling `doStuff(leftHalf)` and `doStuff(rightHalf)`.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>& equationHalf = ((i==0) ? leftHalf : rightHalf);` would work, assuming the second test for `i==0` is in fact a typo and `i!=0` was intended.

Comment: @WhozCraig I corrected my code. I actually meant `i==1`, but this vector will never have a size greater than 2, so that will work. 

Since `std::vector<string> separatedEquation` will never hold more than 2 strings, is is better practice to make it an array?

Comment: @Crysis see my comment below your question.

Comment: Can you point out some of the other typos in my code? I only know of the `i==0, i==0` typo that I fixed.

Comment: Nah looks like you fixed anything I had noticed (the ``i`` equality test was the big one).